# Getting length of <li> when using Bootstrap 4 tab-content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am a bit stuck on this. I am trying to get the length of a list using Bootstrap 4's tab-content. Since the tab is not active on page load, the length is 0. When I open the tab, it is still 0.

I added the html that gets printed as well as the ajax call to get the data.

```js
// print applicant status
if (applicantStatus == 'true') {
  $('#aStatus').html('Applicant');

  // video module count
  var totalModCount = $("#vidList").find("li").length;
  console.log(totalModCount); // 0 Supposed to be 9
  $('#totalCount').html(totalModCount)

  // form total count
  var totalFormCount = $("#vidList").find("li").length;
  console.log(totalFormCount); // 0 Supposed to be 4
  $('#formTotalCount').html(totalFormCount);
}
else {
  $('#aStatus').html('Employee');
};

var listOfTypes = "";
$.each(parsedData, function (index, item) {

  var dateOfCompletion = moment(item.DateCompleted).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
  lastAttempt = moment(item.DateOfExam).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
  isValid = item.Valid;
  isOrientation = item.IsOrientation;
  isInservice = item.IsInservice;

  if (applicantStatus == "true") {
    if (isOrientation) {
      if (isValid) {
        if (item.IsComplete == true) {
          listOfTypes += "<li class='list-group-item disabled videoItem text-success'><a class='video-btn gray' data-toggle='modal' data-src='" + item.URL
          listOfTypes += "' id='tID_" + item.TypeID + "' href='#myModal'>";
          listOfTypes += item.TypeName + "</a>";
          listOfTypes += "<br><p id='typeStatus' value='" + item.TypeID + "' class='completionDate'>Completed on: " + dateOfCompletion + "</p></li>";

        }
        else {
          listOfTypes += "<li class='list-group-item videoItem'><a class='video-btn' data-toggle='modal' data-src='" + item.URL
          listOfTypes += "' id='tID_" + item.TypeID + "' href='#myModal'>";
          listOfTypes += item.TypeName + "</a>";
          listOfTypes += "<br><p id='typeStatus' value='" + item.TypeID + "' class='timeDuration'>Time Duration: " + item.Duration + "</p></li>";
        }
      }
      else {
        listOfTypes += "<li class='list-group-item d-none videoItem'><a class='video-btn' data-toggle='modal' data-src='" + item.URL
        listOfTypes += "' id='tID_" + item.TypeID + "' href='#myModal'>";
        listOfTypes += item.TypeName + "</a>";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class='tab-content'>
  <div id="videoList" class="tab-pane fade">
    <ul class='list-group' id='vidList'>
      <li class="list-group-item videoItem"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item videoItem"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item videoItem"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item videoItem"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item videoItem"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item videoItem"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="formsList" class="tab-pane fade">
    <ul class='list-group' id='fList'>
      <li class="list-group-item formItem"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item formItem"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item formItem"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item formItem"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks fine to me... Are you getting the tabs asynchronously?

Comment: try var totalModCount = $("#vidList li").length;

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman that's correct. they're hidden on page load. when I click on one, it shows the list.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Oria Then you need to do the check after the async call has been done.

Comment: @wahmal no good. thanks anyway.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Oria I have written an answer based on my observation and available code. If you would like to show the full code, perhaps I'll be able to solve it. 

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman my question has been updated.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Oria Saw your code. Slightly unclear. Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Oria Can you try putting your first code block under the `$.each()` block? That might actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had to do to make it work.

Thank you everyone for your help. *I believe my explanations were very confusing, but your input helped me land the answer.*

```
var completedCount = parsedData.filter(function (item) {
  if (item.Valid == true) {
    return item.IsComplete
  }
}).length;
$('#completionCount').html(completedCount);

// totalCount
var totalCount = parsedData.filter(function (item) {
  if (item.IsOrientation == true && item.Valid == true) {
    return item.IsOrientation
  }
}).length;
$('#totalCount').html(totalCount);
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's totally different to what we tried. Ha ha. Glad you got it solved.

Comment: Also, you don't need to check `== true` and you can omit that part.

Answer (score 1):

If the call is *asynchronous*, you need to check after you have loaded the tabs. So take the below code and its respective function into the callback function of the async call and check.

```
var totalModCount = $("#vidList").find("li").length;
```

Until then it's going to be empty.

Comment: I was able to answer my question. Thank you thank you thank you for your help today.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the lists are loaded from an ajax call ? in this case the code you entered must be executed at the callback in the **success** of the call

```
$ajax({
    url : '',
    type: ...,
    success : function(response) {
    // add the <li> </li> AND THEN DO THE COUNT
    var totalModCount = $("#vidList").find("li").length;
    }

})
```

Comment: Yes, I had this before. Here is my previous code: var completedCount = parsedData.filter(function (item) {
                    if (item.Valid == true) {
                        return item.IsComplete
                    }
                }).length;
                $('#completionCount').html(completedCount);

Comment: It unfortunately wasn't counting the items being displayed. Perhaps it was something on my part.